# Qt Creator coding style: How to force new line before the opening brace?

Tags: coding-style, qt-creator

By default there is [no line break](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Coding_Style#967b242cdc0ec9e165a27c31ee8ad0d6) before the opening brace in Qt Creator. How can I override this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of tools for this, "Artistic Style" is the one I use.
http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

Install Artistic Style

QtCreator -> Tools -> Options -> Beautifier

(If it's not present, then enable it in Help -> About Plugins ...)

On the Artistic Style Tab check "Use self-defined style" and click Edit

Enter "--style=allman" (without quotes) in the text box and OK, OK.

Then it is Tools -> Beautifier -> Artistic Style -> Format Current File

To see all the available options (and what "--style=allman" does) see http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Bracket_Style_Options

Comment: alternatively, you can use Beautifier with clang-format and `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman` option.